# Why is $ |1-a|+|a-(-1)| < 1+1$?

Tags: absolute-value, triangle-inequality

> Why is $|1-a|+|a-(-1)| < 1+1$?

This is for proving that $(-1)^n$ does not converge (for this prove you have to use the triangle inequality).

You have to assume that $\lim\limits_{n->∞} (-1)^n = a$, and $a$ is a real number.

quote:

2 = |1 −(−1)| = |1 −a+a−(−1)| ≤ |1 −a|+|a−(−1)| < 1+1= 2.
This absurdity shows our assumption lim(−1)^n = a must be wrong,
so the sequence (−1)^n does not converge.

Comment: do you have any thoughts on this? what is $a$?

Comment: I'm pretty sure it depends on the range of $a$, since for $a=3$, we have $|1-a|+|a-(-1)|=|1-3|+|3+1|=2+4=6$.

Comment: If you're making that assumption, Sam, it should be in the body of the question, not down here in the comments.

Comment: well $|1-a|+|a-(-1)|=2$ if and only if $a\in[-1,1]$ and $|1-a|+|a-(-1)|$ is never less than $2$ for any $a\in\mathbb{R}$

Comment: The opposite assertion is much closer to true.  The true assertion, based on the triangle inequality, is $|1-a|+|a-(-1)| \geq (1+1)$.  This is based on the theorem that $|r| + |s| \geq |r+s|.$

Comment: You do not need the triangle inequality to prove that $(a_n)=(-1)^n$ does not converge.  $(a_n)$ is oscillating between $-1$ and $1$ , hence the difference between consecutive entries is always $2$ , but for the convergence we would need that this difference tends to $0$.

Answer (score 3):

This is false.

The correct statement is

$$|1-a| + |a-(-1)| \ge 2$$

To see it, notice that $|1-a|$ is the distance of $a$ from $1$ and $|a-(-1)|$ is the distance of $a$ from $-1$. If $-1 \le a \le 1$, it is equal to $2$.

For $a < -1$, its distance to $1$ is clearly more than $2$.

For $a > 1$, its distance to $-1$ is clearly more than $2$.

This also implies that $(-1)^n$ diverges as it's distances from $1$ and $-1$ can't be arbitrarily small simultaneously. More generally, for a sequence to converge, you can't have two subsequences that converges to two different values.